# Elasticsearch check if an index is receiving read traffic

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using elasticsearch 6.0.
We have an index in our cluster and would like to know if there are any clients who are querying it.
Is there a way to know if an index is receiving read( get, search, aggregation etc) on an index?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have [monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.0/elasticsearch-metrics.html) enabled on your cluster please have a look on the [index stats api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/indices-stats.html). You'll find a lot of metrics worth to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can see which thread has completed how many `write` tasks completed with this command:

```
GET /_cat/thread_pool/write?v&h=id,node_name,active,rejected,completed
```

or for getting `get` task:

```
GET /_cat/thread_pool/get?v&h=id,node_name,active,rejected,completed
```